# Using a custom ObjectMapper for Spring XD Json to Java Conversion

Tags: spring-xd

Is there an easy way to convert a JSON payload to a Java object using a custom ObjectMapper (Jackson) or do I have to provide a custom type converter. I know that I could use a processor, but somehow it would be nice to use input and output types of the stream definition.

In the second case: Am I even able to provide a custom type converter for application/json to Java?

The documentation states: "The customMessageConverters are added after the standard converters in the order defined. So it is generally easier to add converters for new media types than to replace existing converters."

I bet that there is an existing "application/json" converter - but at a first glance I could not find further information if it is even possible to replace existing converters.

Thanks!
Peter

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [streams.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/streams.xml) You can see the relevant configuration. The configured lists are used to construct a [CompositeMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/converter/CompositeMessageConverter.html) which visits every MessageConverter in list order until it finds one that can do the conversion and returns a non-null result. A CompositeConverter instance is created for each module instance that is configured for conversion (i.e., defines an inputType or outputType value) by filtering the list of candidate message converters, which all inherit [AbstractFromMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/api/org/springframework/xd/dirt/integration/bus/converter/AbstractFromMessageConverter.html). The list is paired down to those which respond *true* to *public boolean supportsTargetMimeType(MimeType mimeType)* (where mimeType is the value of the input/outputType). The CompositeMessageConverter is injected into the corresponding MessageChannel and converts the payload.

There are a couple of things you can do. You can override the *xd.messageConverters* bean definition. For example, you can replace *JsonToPojoMessageConverter* and *PojoToJsonMessageConverter* with your own subclasses. You can also insert your own implementations in the list before the above converters and have your implementation match only specific domain objects for which you need a custom JSON mapper. 
Another possibility is to define your own mime type and provide converters for that mime type as *customMessageConverters*. In any case, follow these guidelines for[extending Spring XD](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#How-to-Add-a-Spring-Bean-to-the-XD-Container)